# Xamarin.Forms UI Test Environment

Tags: xamarin.forms, moq, xamarin.uitest

I am trying to set up my Xamarin.Forms application to use UI Tests. Currently the tests are working fine, but I would like to be able to mock or handle the API calls that the application calls, rather than the actual API calls being executed in the tests.

There appears to be a way that [UITest can detect if it is running in Test Cloud](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/71344/detecting-if-test-is-running-on-test-cloud), but I can't seem to find a way for the application to know if it is running tests locally. I am using an IoC Container to register the various interfaces that interact with these APIs, and would like the `App` constructor to be able to detect if it is running a UITest, then register the appropriate 'actual' interface instances or the 'mock' instances. Is there a known way to handle this?

Comment: How do you run the UITest? Using VS? When you run the UITest for the app and the test return a message?

Comment: Hi Wendy, yes I run it using Visual Studio Professional 2019. I am confused by what you mean with 'test return a message'? The tests as they are run perfectly fine, but I'd like the main app to know if it is currently running a test. Therefore, the application config will behave differently to handle API calls.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue can be solved in many ways, but this is what I actually do:

You can create a dedicated compiler configuration:

[image]

Then, based on the configuration you would manipulate your container boostrap pointing your interfaces to the mock objects.

Whenever you want to run UI tests you would compile this configuration instead of the release configuration.

Comment: Thanks @xleon. That is what I have used in my set up as well. For some reason it has started working now as well. My set up worked by using the following resource, with a 'Test' configuration: https://medium.com/@benjamintodts/cross-platform-environment-aware-configuration-files-in-xamarin-232e7d5ddd80